# Obtener nombre de archivo que se esta leyendo

Tags: c#

Como puedo guardar el nombre del archivo que se esta leyendo y guardarlo en una variable?

```
  string[] lineas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"XXXXX");
```

Comment: A que te refieres exactamente? Puedes simplemente asignar la ruta del archivo a una variable `string` y allí tendras la ruta del archivo en una variable

Comment: pero de donde sale XXXXX ? es una ruta completa al archivo

Comment: Solo es para el ejemplo, obvio es un ruta completa con extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si quieres obtener sólo el nombre del archivo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
string nombreArchivo = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(@"XXXXX");
```

De ésta manera obtienes sólo el nombre del archivo, sin la ruta entera.

Answer (score 4):

Asigna primero el nombre del archivo a una variable tipo string y luego utiliza esa variable para abrir el archivo

Algo así:

```
string nombreArvhivo = @"XXXXX"
string[] lineas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(nombreArchivo);
//nombreArchivo tiene el nombre del archivo leído.
```

Answer (score 4):

Para obtener el nombre de un archivo sabiendo la ruta, lo podes hacer con [`Path.GetFileName(string)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.IO.Path.GetFileName);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) si te interesa conservar la extensión, o [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(string)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) en caso de que prefieras el nombre del archivo sin la misma.

Por ende, bastaría con almacenar la ruta en una variable y hacer uso de alguno de estos métodos.

```
string path = "@XXXX";
string[] lineas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
string nombreArchivoConExtension = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
string nombreArchivoSinExtension = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
```

Asumiendo que `path`  valiese `C:\Info\CATÁLOGOS\ANILAG P1T M12.pdf`

la variable `nombreArchivoConExtension` va a valer `ANILAG P1T M12.pdf` y `nombreArchivoSinExtension` `ANILAG P1T M12`